# Android custom camera surfaceview always fail to take picture

Tags: java, android, camera, surfaceview, android-camera2

I created a custom surface view for camera, to take a picture when button is clicked but it always reset to `onCaptureFailed`

Here is my full code https://codeshare.io/VZAAm3

```
public void captureImage() {
        // Capture an image when the custom button is clicked
        if (cameraDevice != null) {
            try {
                int width = previewSize.getWidth();
                int height = previewSize.getHeight();
                CameraCharacteristics characteristics = cameraManager.getCameraCharacteristics(cameraDevice.getId());
                StreamConfigurationMap map = characteristics.get(CameraCharacteristics.SCALER_STREAM_CONFIGURATION_MAP);
                if(map != null) {
                    Size[] outputSizes = map.getOutputSizes(ImageFormat.JPEG);
                    if (outputSizes != null && outputSizes.length > 0) {
                        width = outputSizes[0].getWidth();
                        height = outputSizes[0].getHeight();
                    }
                }

                try (ImageReader cameraImageReader = ImageReader.newInstance(width, height, ImageFormat.JPEG, 1)) {
                  List<Surface> outputSurface = new ArrayList<>(2);
                  outputSurface.add(cameraImageReader.getSurface());
                  outputSurface.add(new Surface(cameraPreview.getSurfaceTexture()));

                    final CaptureRequest.Builder captureBuilder = cameraDevice.createCaptureRequest(CameraDevice.TEMPLATE_STILL_CAPTURE);
                    captureBuilder.addTarget(cameraImageReader.getSurface());
                    captureBuilder.set(CaptureRequest.CONTROL_MODE, CameraMetadata.CONTROL_MODE_AUTO);

                    //Check orientation base on device
                    int rotation = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getRotation();
                    captureBuilder.set(CaptureRequest.JPEG_ORIENTATION, ORIENTATIONS.get(rotation));

                    cameraDevice.createCaptureSession(outputSurface, new CameraCaptureSession.StateCallback() {
                        @Override
                        public void onConfigured(@NonNull CameraCaptureSession session) {
                            try {
                                session.capture(captureBuilder.build(), new CameraCaptureSession.CaptureCallback() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void onCaptureCompleted(@NonNull CameraCaptureSession session, @NonNull CaptureRequest request, @NonNull TotalCaptureResult result) {
                                        super.onCaptureCompleted(session, request, result);
                                        cameraImageReader.setOnImageAvailableListener(imageReaderListener, null);
                                        Log.e("Capture", "Captured");
                                    }

                                    @Override
                                    public void onCaptureFailed(@NonNull CameraCaptureSession session, @NonNull CaptureRequest request, @NonNull CaptureFailure failure) {
                                        super.onCaptureFailed(session, request, failure);
                                        int reason = failure.getReason();
                                        int sequenceId = failure.getSequenceId();
                                        Log.e("Capture", "Capture failed with reason: " + reason + ", sequenceId: " + sequenceId);
                                    }
                                }, null);
                            } catch (CameraAccessException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onConfigureFailed(@NonNull CameraCaptureSession cameraCaptureSession) {

                        }
                    }, null);
                } catch (CameraAccessException e) {
                    // Handle camera access exception
                }
            } catch (CameraAccessException e) {
                // Handle camera access exception
            }
        }
    }
```